# Delphi xe8 - "Invalid authorization specification" from the provider

Tags: delphi, ms-access, service, delphi-xe8

I have a DELPHI XE8 application that uses Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 as the provider to open and work with ACCESS database files.  When I install the application on a Windows Server 2012 box and log in to that server, everything works fine and happy.

I am touching the file with the following:

> TAdoConnection.ConnectionString :=
>   'Provider="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";Data
>   Source="d:\directory\myfile.MDB";Persist Security Info=False;
>   TAdoConnection.Open;

I took the exact same piece of code and put it inside a service, running on the same machine and when it tries to open the file I get the error "Invalid authorization specification" from the provider.

I am pretty sure this is happening because it is a "Service" and does not have a user profile but I have not been able to find anything helpful regarding this error.

Any thoughts or direction would be greatly appreciated.